# How to add whitespace & punctuation marks to capture first group with regex? How to stop certain tabs dividing into two columns within LibreOffice?

Tags: php, regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Anyone help me out. Been trying to get this regex working, and it’s nearly there. They all seem to be correct, but the first one should be:

word: el, la
gender: art
word_en: the (+m, f)

The first test string is:

```
1

el, la art the (+m, f)
• el diccionario tenía también frases útiles – the dictionary also had
useful phrases
2055835 | 201481381
```

The other issue is that I’ve been trying to simply copy info. from the ‘Substitution’ section into LibreOffice. All I want to do is create 6 columns for the data. The Problem is that the 6th column (sent_en) can sometimes divide between columns ‘G’ and ‘A’, instead of all the data for sent_en being in column ‘G’. If you copy the data below ‘Substitution’ into LibreOffice Calc, you’ll get a better idea of what I mean. I just can’t figure this out, and if someone can help me out I’d really appreciate it. Thanks.

Here’s the link https://regex101.com/r/m3yySN/2/

```
^

(?<frequency>[0-9]+) \W+
(?<word>\pL+\W?) \h+
(?<gender> [\pL()]+ (?:, \h* [\pL()]+)* ) \h+
(?<word_en> [^•]*[^•\s]) \h* \R

• \h*
(?<sent_esp> [^–]*[^\s–] ) \s*–\s*
(?<sent_en> .* (?:\R .*)*? ) \h* \R

(?<num1> [0-9]+) \h* \| \h*
(?<num2> .*\S)

\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t
```

Comment: You need to include all code in your actual question (copy/paste). Links to third party services can be used as an example, but shouldn't be required to understand the question. If the link changes/gets removed, this question will be useless for future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A follow-up question is posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/141538/how-do-you-prevent-a-tab-delimited-txt-file-from-dividing-between-rows-for-each-group/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was a bit hairy, but after all, just a small adjustment was needed:

```
^
(?<frequency>[0-9]+) \W+
(?<word>\pL+(?:,\h\pL+|\W)*) \h+
(?<gender> [\pL()]+ (?:, \h* [\pL()]+)* ) \h+
(?<word_en> [^•]*[^•\s]) \h* \R
• \h*
(?<sent_esp> [^–]*[^\s–] ) \s*–\s*
(?<sent_en> .* (?:\R .*)*? ) \h* \R
(?<num1> [0-9]+) \h* \| \h*
(?<num2> .*\S)
```

[Results](https://regex101.com/r/c5t1rV/1) look good to me now.

Comment: Hey, really appreciate it. Thanks for your help.